# Create ec2 instance with ruby and connect to the created machine

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

After i create the instance using instances.create, i need to connect to the machine and perform some operations.
The question is - what is the best way to know that the creation has finished and i can connect to the machine ?

The machine's state right after creating it is 'running', so how can i know when the machine finished its initialization and i can ssh to it ?

I saw an existing code where its done by ssh'ing every X seconds, and if its get timeout than it means that the machine is still initializing.

I am looking for a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also looking for a similar solution, and I found a test on the AWS Ruby SDK that does just that: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/samples/ec2/run_instance.rb

```
begin
  Net::SSH.start(instance.ip_address, "ec2-user",
                 :key_data => [key_pair.private_key]) do |ssh|
  puts "Running 'uname -a' on the instance yields:"
  puts ssh.exec!("uname -a")
end
rescue SystemCallError, Timeout::Error => e
  # port 22 might not be available immediately after the instance finished
  launching
  sleep 1
  retry
end
```

It might not be the cleanest solution, but it's a solution Amazon adopts.

Comment: Yea. thats what i ended with :)

Answer (score 1):

Once the instance is created, you get the instances ID. So, use that instance ID to check the **"Instance Status"**. Each instance has to go through 2 `status checks`: **System Status Check** and **Instance Status Check.**

I have observed that once both these checks are passed, the instance is ready to be logged in.

The corresponding Method in ruby sdk which pulls this data is **[describe_instance_status](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/V20140501.html#describe_instance_status-instance_method)**

Comment: The problem is that even though that the machine state is "running", the status check is still on "Initializing"

Comment: The instance will be in "running" state very soon, but Instance/status checks take some time to complete.